# Analyze Embarcadero RAD Studio project with clang analyzer

Tags: c++builder, static-analysis, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I would like to know is it possible to analyze Embarcadero RAD Studio C++ project with [Clang Static Analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). As far as I understand I need a makefile or something any and ability to build the project with clang. But Embarcadero uses it's own C++ extension, so code can't be compiled with clang.

If analyzing is possible (at least for separate files) it would be good if someone post a sequence of steps what I need to do.

Comment: Modern versions of C++Builder use clang-based C++ compilers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau unfortunally my is not modern. XE.

Comment: @RemyLebeau in case of modern version, if you know an answer it would be great to post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out that since RadStudio XE2, it has integrated C++ Analyzer.

From my initial tests, in RadStudio 10.2 it seems to be based on Clang Static Analyzer (not 100% sure)

Here is video instructions for XE2 https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41862
In Tokyo you access it from menu View->Tool Windows->C++ Analyzer.

My preliminary results are: very slow but pretty helpful results with lots of possible tweaking.

Comment: It seems in C++ Builder 10.3.3, C++ 17 standard is not supported by the static analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [CppDepend](https://www.cppdepend.com) which use Clang and Clang-Tidy to report all the issues reported by them.

However you have to use the [BuildMonitor](https://www.cppdepend.com/BuildMonitor) tool to intercept your compilation and link commands before analyze it with CppDepend.

Answer (score 0):

If clang static analyzer is a hard requirement, then I don't know of a solution. But if static analysis in general is your requirement, then GrammaTech CodeSonar supports Embarcadero.